# How do you dispatch an action along with a DOM event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm picking up working with react and redux, while handling state locally I am able to pass events along with onChange handlers so as to access the value with event.target.value and set them to state. Unfortunately, I am unable to pass the event to MapDispatchToProps

I have tried passing the event along with the prop assigned to the onChange handler

## This is my component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MarkDownBox extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="markedContainer">
                <div className="markedHeader" ><h1>Raw Mark Down</h1></div>
                <textarea name="markdownarea" id="markdownarea" value={this.props.message} onChange={this.props.onChangeText}></textarea>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
      message: state.text
    }
  }
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
      onChangeText: (event) => dispatch({type: 'onChangeText',event} )
    
    }
  }
  
  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MarkDownBox);
```

### This is my reducer

```
const initialState = {
    text: 'Sample text'
}


const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const newState = {...state}
    switch(action.type){
        case 'OnChangeText':
            newState.text = action.event.target.value;
            return newState    
         default: 
         return state
    }
}


export default reducer;
```

MapStateToProps works fine as it sets the value of the text field. The text field, however, does not record any changes.

Comment: In your text area, change the onChange event to this:
onChange={this.props.onChangeText}
This should pass the event automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reducer your case `OnChangeText` start with uppercase and `dispatch({type: 'onChangeText',event})` with lowercase, so ideally to be like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return{
   onChangeText: (event) => dispatch({type: 'ON_CHANGE_TEXT',payload: event.target.value} )

 }
}
```

And in the reducer:

```
 case 'ON_CHANGE_TEXT':
        return {
           ...state,
           text: action.payload
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the reducer, try this:

```
switch(action.type){
    case 'OnChangeText':
        // To make sure you are getting the correct value
        console.log(action.event.target.value)

        return {
         ...state,
         text: action.event.target.value
         }
     default: 
     return state
}
```